# Calling std::shuffle from multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, c++14, stdvector

I'm trying to shuffle copy of vector in multiple threads. My code:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> rw{1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    std::mutex m;
    auto multithread_shuffle = [rw, &m]() {
        unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
        std::shuffle (rw.begin(), rw.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));
        std::lock_guard lock(m);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rw.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << "rw[" << i << "] = " << rw[i] << std::endl;
        }
    };
    std::thread t1(multithread_shuffle);
    std::thread t2(multithread_shuffle);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

But unfortunately, I'm getting a lot of warnings and this two errors:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'swap(const int&, const int&)'
   swap(*__a, *__b);
   ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
```

I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: What includes are you using?

Comment: This is all going to happen so fast that odds are really good that both threads will get the same seed and perform identical shuffles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the vector becomes `const` when copied into the lambda's capture parameters. Consider:

```
int main() {
    int x = 15;
    auto func = [x]{//Capture by value
        x = 20;//Does not compile!
    };
}
```

For all intents and purposes, `x` is a `const int`, not an `int`.

You can get the same problem in your code with only a minor change:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> rw{1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    std::mutex m;
    auto multithread_shuffle = [rw, &m]() {
        rw[0] = 3; //Does not compile!
        rw = std::vector<int>{4,3,2,1}; //Does not compile!
        unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
        std::shuffle (rw.begin(), rw.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));
        std::lock_guard lock(m);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rw.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << "rw[" << i << "] = " << rw[i] << std::endl;
        }
    };
    std::thread t1(multithread_shuffle);
    std::thread t2(multithread_shuffle);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

You need to explicitly allocate a local copy of the vector if you want it to be mutable.

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> rw{1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    std::mutex m;
    auto multithread_shuffle = [rw, &m]() {
        auto rw_mutable = rw;
        unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
        std::shuffle (rw_mutable.begin(), rw_mutable.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));
        std::lock_guard lock(m);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rw.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << "rw_mutable[" << i << "] = " << rw_mutable[i] << std::endl;
        }
    };
    std::thread t1(multithread_shuffle);
    std::thread t2(multithread_shuffle);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

You could also just declare the lambda `mutable`:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> rw{1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    std::mutex m;
    auto multithread_shuffle = [rw, &m]() mutable {
        unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
        std::shuffle (rw.begin(), rw.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));
        std::lock_guard lock(m);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rw.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << "rw[" << i << "] = " << rw[i] << std::endl;
        }
    };
    std::thread t1(multithread_shuffle);
    std::thread t2(multithread_shuffle);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```